# debugging applyIndicators error in Quanstrat

Tags: r, quantstrat

Ran into an interesting error trying to learn quantstrat with the applyIndicators function. I have 3 indicators, lagATR, RSI, and SMA applied to the same data over the same period.  All three indicators together generate an error using the applyIndicators function.  Any pair of indicators do not. The code is below.
This code is primarily taken from two blog entries ([part 1](http://www.r-bloggers.com/nuts-and-bolts-of-quantstrat-part-i/) and [part 2](http://www.r-bloggers.com/nuts-and-bolts-of-quantstrat-part-ii/)).  The code is structured to initialize some variables, get price data for XLB.  Then it runs 4 scenarios: all 3 indicators and then each pair.  I'd appreciate help in understanding why all 3 indicators generates an error and the pairs do not. Thanks.

---

```
#Part 1 from http://www.r-bloggers.com/nuts-and-bolts-of-quantstrat-part-i/
require(IKTrading)
require(quantstrat)
require(PerformanceAnalytics)

initDate="1990-01-01"
from="2003-01-01"
to="2012-12-31"
options(width=70)

currency('USD')
Sys.setenv(TZ="UTC")

options("getSymbols.warning4.0"=FALSE)
rm(list=ls(.blotter), envir=.blotter)
symbols <- "XLB" #SPDR Materials sector
getSymbols(symbols, from=from, to=to, src="yahoo", adjust=TRUE)
stock(symbols, currency="USD", multiplier=1)


#trade sizing and initial equity settings
tradeSize <- 100000
initEq <- tradeSize*length(symbols)



#Part 2 from http://www.r-bloggers.com/nuts-and-bolts-of-quantstrat-part-ii/
#parameters
pctATR <- .02
period <- 10
atrOrder <- TRUE

nRSI <- 2
buyThresh <- 20
sellThresh <- 80
nSMA <- 200

#FIRST RUN - TRY ALL 3 INDICATORS: 
strategy.st <- portfolio.st <- account.st <- "DollarVsATRos"
rm.strat(strategy.st)
initPortf(portfolio.st, symbols=symbols, initDate=initDate, currency='USD')
initAcct(account.st, portfolios=portfolio.st, initDate=initDate, currency='USD',initEq=initEq)
initOrders(portfolio.st, initDate=initDate)
strategy(strategy.st, store=TRUE)
#indicators
add.indicator(strategy.st, name="lagATR", 
              arguments=list(HLC=quote(HLC(mktdata)), maType="SMA", n=period), 
              label="atrX")
add.indicator(strategy.st, name="RSI",
              arguments=list(price=quote(Cl(mktdata)), maType="SMA", n=nRSI),
              label="rsi")
add.indicator(strategy.st, name="SMA",
              arguments=list(x=quote(Cl(mktdata)), n=nSMA),
              label="sma")
test <- applyIndicators(strategy.st, mktdata=OHLC(XLB))
head(test,12)

#SECOND RUN - TRY lagATR and RSI INDICATORS: 
strategy.st <- portfolio.st <- account.st <- "DollarVsATRos"
rm.strat(strategy.st)
initPortf(portfolio.st, symbols=symbols, initDate=initDate, currency='USD')
initAcct(account.st, portfolios=portfolio.st, initDate=initDate, currency='USD',initEq=initEq)
initOrders(portfolio.st, initDate=initDate)
strategy(strategy.st, store=TRUE)
#indicators
add.indicator(strategy.st, name="lagATR", 
              arguments=list(HLC=quote(HLC(mktdata)), maType="SMA", n=period), 
              label="atrX")
add.indicator(strategy.st, name="RSI",
              arguments=list(price=quote(Cl(mktdata)), maType="SMA", n=nRSI),
              label="rsi")
test <- applyIndicators(strategy.st, mktdata=OHLC(XLB))
head(test,12)

#THIRD RUN - TRY RSI and SMA INDICATORS: 
strategy.st <- portfolio.st <- account.st <- "DollarVsATRos"
rm.strat(strategy.st)
initPortf(portfolio.st, symbols=symbols, initDate=initDate, currency='USD')
initAcct(account.st, portfolios=portfolio.st, initDate=initDate, currency='USD',initEq=initEq)
initOrders(portfolio.st, initDate=initDate)
strategy(strategy.st, store=TRUE)
#indicators
add.indicator(strategy.st, name="RSI",
              arguments=list(price=quote(Cl(mktdata)), maType="SMA", n=nRSI),
              label="rsi")
add.indicator(strategy.st, name="SMA",
              arguments=list(x=quote(Cl(mktdata)), n=nSMA),
              label="sma")
test <- applyIndicators(strategy.st, mktdata=OHLC(XLB))
head(test,12)

#FOURTH RUN - TRY lagATR and SMA INDICATORS: 
strategy.st <- portfolio.st <- account.st <- "DollarVsATRos"
rm.strat(strategy.st)
initPortf(portfolio.st, symbols=symbols, initDate=initDate, currency='USD')
initAcct(account.st, portfolios=portfolio.st, initDate=initDate, currency='USD',initEq=initEq)
initOrders(portfolio.st, initDate=initDate)
strategy(strategy.st, store=TRUE)
#indicators
add.indicator(strategy.st, name="lagATR", 
              arguments=list(HLC=quote(HLC(mktdata)), maType="SMA", n=period), 
              label="atrX")
add.indicator(strategy.st, name="SMA",
              arguments=list(x=quote(Cl(mktdata)), n=nSMA),
              label="sma")
test <- applyIndicators(strategy.st, mktdata=OHLC(XLB))
head(test,12)
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Ilya helped me out. I installed the latest version of TTR from r-forge and the code now works.  FWIW, my prev version of TTR was 0.22. Now it shows 0.22-0.1